# Add a preview of Stack Overflow links in mod flags on hover

Tags: feature-request, moderation, moderator-tools

Lots of people flag posts and, in the "Other" explanation, add links.  The vast majority of these are of the type

> exact duplicate of [stackoverflow.com/questions/4275311](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275311)

The only way to evaluate the exactness of the duplication is to click the link and view it in another tab.

Can there be, for links to the same domain, a quickie preview on hover?  Title, the first four lines, and the user who submitted is usually enough to determine if the question is an **exact** *exact duplicate* which requires further moderator massaging (merging posts or users).

Comment: For your future reference, Will, *duplicity* is about deception.

Comment: @GraceNote: Can I has words fun evar?