# Change text of links on Stack Exchange network from URL to post title in moderator queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, hyperlinks, moderator-tools

Currently, when a link, such as something being marked as an exact duplicate shows up in the moderator queue, a non-descript url is shown as a note to the moderator:

[image: exact duplicate moderator note]

However, I'd like a more meaningful link to be displayed where the title of the question (even if it's an answer) is the text of the link instead of the URL being the text of the link:

[image: improved exact duplicate moderator note]

Comment: What benefit is there? You still need to click the link to make sure it's actually a duplicate

Comment: From an efficiency standpoint, I can make a quick determination as to whether or not I want to handle the flag at all at that point.  There are some duplicates that you can tell are going to be very, very hairy, and if there simply isn't the time for a moderator to process it, this would help them make that determination before it's too late (I agree, you have to click the link at *some* point).  Also, you're focusing on the exact duplicate case, which while probably the most common, isn't the only flag where links from the SE network appear, this feature request applies to those as well.

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93300/add-a-preview-of-stack-overflow-links-in-mod-flags-on-hover)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the auto flag types that show lists of posts will now have the title as the link's text.

Comment: Custom "other..." flags won't have this formatting for their urls - checking into what I can reuse in the codebase to make it happen.

Comment: I don't mind custom other flags, that's difficult, because you have to parse the message.  But automated stuff where you *do* have the ID, that would be a huge win.