# Duplicate flag links in 10k tools are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

Oy! [Duplicate answer flag](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?flagtype=answerduplicateanswerauto) links are broken, on Stack Overflow at least:

> [image]

Nothing clickable here.

Markup: `Duplicate answers: &lt;a href=&#39;/a/17872807&#39;&gt;17872807&lt;/a&gt;`

Comment: This is probably a result of my private bug report that was just fixed where HTML was not being escaped properly (and users could run JavaScript in their flag reasons).

Comment: So, what you're saying is, we can blame you.

Comment: First it's not enough escaping, then it's too much escaping. Can't we just blame markup languages in general?

Comment: I'll spin the Wheel of Blame, @animuson

Comment: Clearly it can't be my fault since I am not on the Wheel of Blame.

Comment: Just think of it as we're doubly protecting you from XSS :)  Working on it now (it's not a fast fix, as we're storing a description and html in the flag text - it should just be a list of post ids stored).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and the question links now have their titles in the text.

Comment: Cool. I'm not going to file this, because I have a disturbing recent trend of filing trivial little bug reports, but there's a little bit of yellow spilling over onto the timestamp, just after the duplicate answer links.

Comment: Ah, whitespace in html, how I love you.  I'll check it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 8):

While we're at it, I'd like to see the post title (and not just an ID) be placed as the link text, as it will aid in making decisions from the queue; [so] gets a lot of dupe answer flags and just seeing the ID of the post doesn't do much in helping ascertain what to do with them.

This a specific form of [Change text of links on Stack Exchange network from URL to post title in moderator queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121316/change-text-of-links-on-stack-exchange-network-from-url-to-post-title-in-moderat) but for this flag (figured might as well put this in if the whole thing is broken).

Comment: I'll do this, too.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Yay!